# password encryption program

Tags: c++, password-encryption

Hi I am working on an authentication program in which the user enters their name which is encoded (encrypted) and compared against a list of authorized ciphers. If the name is accepted the user may proceed, if not the user has 2 further attempts. Your program will accommodate 4 named users, ‘hardcoded’ into the program.

The name is to be encoded by shifting the letters of the alphabet by 11 places, so 'a' becomes 'i', 'b' becomes 'm' etc. So the name “Joe Bloggs” would be encoded as “Uzp Mwzrrd”. Encoding has to wrap around so that the letter after 'z' is 'a' and therefore 'z' encodes to 'k'.

Below is the code I have but I am struggling with the encryption part. I'm obviously not requesting anyone do it for me but I was hoping someone could give me some hints on how to go about doing this. I'm really at a lose.

```
bool login() {

const string name;
string nameAttempt;
int attempts = 0;


cout << "enter name" << endl;
cin >> nameAttempt;

LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt);

//cout << "nameAttempt: " << Authenticate.getNameAttempt() << endl;
//cout << "name: " << Authenticate.getName() << endl;


if (Authenticate.getName() == Authenticate.getNameAttempt()) {
return true;
} 
else
while(Authenticate.getName() != Authenticate.getNameAttempt())
{       
if(attempts++ ==2)//.. a loop for two more attempts
{
return false;
}
std::cout<<"Incorrect name. Try again"<< endl;
std::cout<< "" << endl;

std::cout << "Enter Name:"<< endl;
cin >>nameAttempt;
LogIn Authenticate(name, nameAttempt);
    }
}


int main()
{

bool login();

bool loggedin = login();

if(loggedin) {
    cout << "Password Correct" << endl;
}

if(!loggedin) {
    cout << "Incorrect Password" << endl;
    cout << "Program will now terminate" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}

cout << "you are now free to enter lift" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Why** are you asking the same question over and over again with a frequency of 1 hour?? Please go to the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the policies of the site before posting here!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually the questions are asking different things although they are related to the same program.

Comment: At the very least, learn how to post code *correctly, with proper indenting*!

Answer (score 0):

- Tip 1: it is not hard to get the number of a letter in the alphabet: `char c; int number = c -'a';`.
- Tip 2: you can use `%` to achieve the cycle shift: `int shifted_number = (number + 11) % 26;`
- Tip 3: you can get the character from a number: `char new_char = number + 'a';`
- Tip 4: you may need to deal with capital letters too if they are allowed.